# Orientjs create vertex with a set property containing a Link and Sequence property

Tags: node.js, orientdb, orientdb2.2, orientjs

I am using Orientjs to create a vertex with some properties and one **link property "Relation"** and one **sequence property "PersonID"**. Though I dont know how could I achieve the following:-

```
var trx = this.db.let('Person',function(p){
    p.create('vertex','Person')
    .set({
         "Name": "ABC",
         "Relation": "select from RelationType where TypeID = " + ID,
         "PersonID": "sequence('personid').next()"
         })
    }).commit().return('$Person').all()
```

The "ID" in the above query is from the input. **I am not sure how could I handle the nested query for Link property and Sequence property**. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use db.rawExpression() to accept the queries as is. The following is the solution

```
var trx = this.db.let('Person',function(p){
p.create('vertex','Person')
.set({
     "Name": "ABC",
     "Relation": db.rawExpression("select from RelationType where TypeID = " + ID),
     "PersonID": db.rawExpression("sequence('personid').next()")
     })
}).commit().return('$Person').all()
```